# Is it necessary to include all levels as random intercepts in a multilevel model when they are perfectly nested?

Tags: multilevel-analysis, nested-data, intercept

I am running a mixed-effects model in R and I want to have random intercepts for two sampling levels, `country` and `site`.  The variable `site` is perfectly nested within the level `country`.  So, is it necessary to model a separate term for the random intercept of `country`, or will simply modeling the error for `site` be suitable?

I.e., would the model

```
lmer(outcome ~ predictor + (1|country) + (1|site))
```

have any benefit over the model

```
lmer(outcome ~ predictor + (1|site))
```

Comment: I think you meant to use random intercepts in your title? Do you have multiple sites for each country?

Comment: Thanks @IsabellaGhement.  I did mean random intercepts.  And I do have random sites for each country.  I should add that I am mostly interested in getting good estimates for my (fixed) predictor variable.

Comment: There may be a country characteristic that effects your predictor. I would add the country level, though I'm relatively new to MLM.

Comment: If `site` is nested within `country`, then the correct specification of the random effects would be: `(1|country/site)`. For more information, see [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/228814/21054). Your current specification is for crossed random effects.